# preparation methods of nicotinoyl glycine

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, experimental-chemistry

How can we prepare nicotinoyl glycine  from nicotinic acid ?Is that possible by reaction between nicotinic acid and glycine?

Answer (score 1):

As a microscale laboratory method, it should be possible to react nicotinic acid with, e.g., thionyl chloride, yielding nicotinoyl chloride (the acid chloride of nicotinic acid). This can be reacted with glycine to yield the desired product. Unfortunately, glycine would exist predominantly in zwitterionic form at neutral pH, so I would guess that pre-treatment of the glycine with base would probably be required prior to the reaction with nicotinoyl chloride.